# What are some of the ways to avoid/handle long method signature?

Tags: java, oop

I feel this method signature is too long. Is there a more sensible or elegant way of re-writing this?

```
  private Email createMail(long actualFileSize, String from, String recipient, String title,
      String emailContent, MultipartFile attachment,
      File file) {
    Email mail = null;
    if (actualFileSize <= Long.parseLong(emailFileSizeLimit)) {
     mail = new Email(from, recipient, title,emailContent, null, file);
    } else mail = new Email(from, recipient, title,emailContent, null, null);
    return mail;
  }
```

Comment: You could have a custom class whose properties match the signature's parameters, and use that instead as the `sendMail` method's parameter. Handy especially if you use that class as a builder.

Comment: @Mena The only meaningful change there is you've made it possible for someone to not set one of the properties, even though every one of them is required.

Comment: You never actually use the attachment that you pass in.

Comment: @Servy not necessarily. If you have control over the `sendMail` implementation and implement some validation within your custom class, you're fine.

Comment: @Mena That's just turned compile time validation that you have all of the parameters into a runtime check.  Again, you're making it possible for someone to mess up, (whether the mistake results in buggy behavior or an exception, it's still a problem) and getting nothing in exchange for it.

Comment: @Servy yes you're getting *something* in exchange for it ("it" being *your* assumption in terms of design), i.e. much better-looking code.

Comment: @mena i updated the method name to createEmail and not sendEmail because the method creates email objects, it does not send them.

Comment: @JoshUzo I don't think that would change anything tbh.

Comment: @Mena How is the code any "better looking" than passing values to a function?  And even if you think it looks better, you've made the code *behave* objectively worse by introducing a likely source of bugs.

Comment: @Servy again, that's your assumption. My suggestion improves on the telescopic anti-pattern in terms of general design. Assumptions on where and how the data can be validated are not part of it. Note also that the distinction you make about compile-time vs runtime validation doesn't make any sense. You can always pass `null`s / bad values to the current method, which is a valid invocation at compile-time and will blow up at runtime all the same.

Comment: It's not an assumption.  It's a fact.  Your code has introduced a very likely possible bug, whereas the original code *can't* have that bug.  That's not an assumption.  Passing an invalid value, and *not passing a value at all* are not the same thing.   Yes, if there are certain values of a given type that aren't valid, then you can't validate that at compile time, but what you *can* do at compile time is ensure that the caller is always providing a value.  That a given solution can't be perfect isn't a reason to use a solution that has *additional* problems.

Comment: @Servy let's use an example of what you are trying to say. E.g. the `EmailDetailsBuilder` class is built with a `null` "from" field, **and** not validated before passing to the method, **and** not validated within the method. --> the email sending will throw some form of exception. Now imagine the case where the method itself holds the original list of parameters, and `from` happens to be passed as `null`. Same exact behavior. Where is the bug?

Comment: @Servy Going further. Say the `EmailDetailsBuilder` class does not feature a `from` field at all. Better even: it will be impossible for the implementation of `sendMail` to retrieve that data, and the failure will happen at compile-time (just as if you omitted `from` from the original signature). Where is the bug?

Comment: @Mena The fact that two programs both have one possible bug if used improperly doesn't change the fact that there are *different* possible bugs that one program prevents and the other doesn't.  Again, one not being perfect doesn't change the fact that it has advantages over the other.  It's not all or nothing.  The goal of the code is to remove as many possible bugs as it can.  Sometimes it can't remove all of them, but that isn't a reason to not remove the bugs that it *can* prevent.

Comment: @Servy we do agree on that. What I'm challenging here is your statement that a pattern aimed at containing telescopic argument lists is less solid than the original argument list because "handling data as a single class introduces bugs while handling data as a long list of method parameters doesn't". To me, it's pretty much the same risk, and the long parameter list yields no visible advantage over using a custom wrapper. (Edit: I may be over-simplifying your claim but I think we understand each other).

Comment: @Mena You've changed an argument from being mandatory to being optional, when the actual logic of the code has it as being mandatory.  That's introducing possible bugs in the program in which someone fails to provide the required value.  That's not an equal risk.  One program has a risk of the value not being provided, one doesn't have any risk at all.  All because you prefer listing required arguments as if they're optional, for...what reason?   You're just stating that marking a required argument as being optional is inherently better for so me reason, and it's not.

Comment: @Servy that's not exactly true though. All nullable parameters of the method are by their own definition "optional" in terms of having a value. And in terms of compile-time "validation" (i.e. whether the parameters even exist): If you build your wrapper as correctly as you've written your method signature, then all parameters will be there. Finally, neither the method's body in OP's question, nor the code I actually haven't posted contain any form of runtime validation, so it's pretty much exactly the same risk from an abstract perspective! Which is why I insist you're making assumptions.

Comment: @Mena There's a *big* difference between a possible value of a type being invalid in a given context and *no value being provided at all*.  Yes, it might be possible for someone to provide an invalid value, but you *can* ensure that they're providing a value.  It's a lot easier to forget to provide a value at all than to go out of your way to provide an invalid value.  It will stand out much more as being wrong code that requires fixing.  Your proposed refactor makes it very easy to forget to provide a value at all.

Comment: "If you build your wrapper as correctly as you've written your method signature, then all parameters will be there."  And yet that's not the wrapper you proposed, nor the wrapper anyone posted in comments.  Sure, if you *correctly* implemented the factory pattern in a way that it was literally impossible to create the object without providing each of the values, you could end up with something that was just as good as the code they already have, but that's a lot of work to get back to where they started.

Comment: @Servy I give up

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This seems a good fit for the [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), where you need to construct a new object in an elaborate way:

```
public class EmailBuilder {
  private Email mail;
  private String from;
  private String recipient;
  // other properties

  public EmailBuilder withFrom(String from) {
    this.from = from;
    return this;
  }
  public EmailBuilder withRecipient(String recipient) {
    this.recipient = recipient;
    return this;
  }
  public Email send() {
    mail = new Email(from, recipient, title,emailContent, null, file);
    return mail;
  }
}
```

usage

```
Email mail = new EmailBuilder()
   .withFrom("John Doe")
   .withRecipient("Mary Doe")
   .with...
   .send();
```

Comment: Great, but `send()`  should probably be renamed `create()` since no email is sent.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr

```
if (actualFileSize <= Long.parseLong(emailFileSizeLimit)) {
    file = null;
}

return new Email(from, recipient, title,emailContent, null, file);
```

1) Refactor. 
If you think there is too much parameters you devide the method into smaller, manageable methods.

```
if (actualFileSize <= Long.parseLong(emailFileSizeLimit)) {
    file = null;
}

createMail(from, recipient, title,emailContent, null, file);

******

private Email createMail(long actualFileSize, String from, String recipient, String 
    title, String emailContent, MultipartFile attachment, File file) {
   return new Email(from, recipient, title,emailContent, null, file);
}
```

2) DTO. 
you supply parameters in dto and pass it as a request/response throughout your chain, using element you need when you need. When you need to increate, you add more attributes. You supply them by setters and pass when needed

3) Builder. 
You have logic done in class that returns itself after finishing with it's operation. You  can execute next operation by calling different operation on same class and return result.

```
Mail mail = mailBuilder.addName(name).add(stuff).compile(); // will call constructor inside
```

4) Factory

have factory contain all the methods and let it decide what methods call. It can static or managed

```
factory.createBasicMail(name);
factory.createFileMail(name, file);
```

ps: for your mental health use Lombok